# Continue when a Future.failed(new Exception("")) is returned in Scala

Tags: scala

How do I handle if a future returns a failed exception?

The scenario is that my code calls `getValue()`, maps the result to `verifyValue()` and then I want to be able to handle the case where the result of getValue() is `Future.failed(new Exception("message"))`. However when I run this, if the result of getValue() is a failed future it just throws the exception rather than handling it.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how I would do this?

```
def method(): Future[JsObject] = {
    getValue().flatMap(verifyValue(_))
}

def getValue(): Future[JsObject] = {
    try {
        value1 <- getValue1()
        value2 <- getValue2(value1)
    } yield {
        value2
    }
}

def verifyValue(result: Any): Future[JsObject] = {
  result match {
    case e: Exception =>
      getValue()
    case json: JsObject => Future.successful(json)
  }
}
```

Update:
I don't think I made this clear with the original question, but the reason why I flatmap the value is that I don't want to explicitly have to wait for any of the futures in my code, and therefore I don't want to use Future.onComplete{} to resolve the value.

Update 2:
Another thing that might not be clear is that if it throws an exception, I want to call another method. I don't want it to just handle the exception, it is going to log the exception and then call another method whose return value is of the same type as getValue().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using the Future.fallbackTo() method.

```
def method(): Future[JsObject] = {
    getValue().fallbackTo(method1()).fallbackTo(method2()).fallbackTo(method3())
}
```

If the future from the first `getValue()` fails, it will call `method1()`. If that also fails, it will call `method2()` etc. If one of the methods succeeds, it will return that value. If none of the methods succeed, it will return the failed future from `getValue()`.

This solution isn't ideal, as I would preferably want to include all four of the exceptions thrown if all of the tries fail, but it at least allows me to retry the `getValue()` method.

Comment: Sounds like you want http://johnkurkowski.com/posts/accumulating-multiple-failures-in-a-ValidationNEL/

Comment: That sounds amazing!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm too lazy to type up a bounty-worthy answer, and also the post does a pretty good job explaining the concepts :-)

Answer (score 6):

Use `recover` or `recoverWith`

recover or recoverWith are called when future fails with an exception. In the recover block you can give the alternative value.

`recoverWith` unlike `recover` takes future of something

```
getValue().recover { case th =>
  //based on the exception type do something here
  defaultValue //returning some default value on failure
}
```

Comment: If I try to do that, getValue2(value1) has a compilation error of "Type mismatch, expected: String, actual: Object", even though in the recovery I just call getValue() again.

Comment: Please stop upvoting this.
This does not work, the recover and recoverWith methods only handle the exception, you cannot call another method that could return with a successful value, which is what my objective is.

Comment: @annedroiid - can you post, in your question, at least the type signatures of all the relevant methods, and the exact error message you are getting? Btw, `recover` and `recoverWith` quite clearly let you compute and return a successful value. See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@recover[U>:T](pf:PartialFunction[Throwable,U])(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[U]

Comment: "Expression of type Future[JsObject] doesn't conform to expected type _U" is the error when I try to do ".recover{case e: Exception => getValue()}"

Comment: @annedroiid - since `getValue` returns a `Future`, you need to use `recoverWith` here, not `recover`. Take a look at the API docs I linked above.

Answer (score 1):

```
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}

f.onComplete {
  case Success(value) => // do sth with value
  case Failure(error) => // do sth with error
}
```

You can use onComplete in your method(), see link below for other options as well:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/concurrent/Future.html